# how to know where is the register variable stored?

Tags: c

I knew that register variables are stored in CPU registers.

And the same variables are stored in stack if the CPU registers are busy/full.

how can i know that the variable is stored in stack or CPU register?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to examine the assembly language output from your compiler.

Comment: you assumptions are wrong and the last question can't be answered since you have no direct control in this.

Comment: @GregHewgill not really, also there are variables such as the amount of cache that are hardware dependent and you can't predict how much cache the cpu will have. Even if you can read your assembly: what is the point ?

Comment: @user1824407 - no, cache does not affect register vs. memory location of a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am agree with Mr. Unwind's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053231/how-to-know-where-is-the-register-variable-stored/14053246#14053246), but upto some extend this way may be helpful to you:

file name `x.c`:

```
int main(){
    register int i=0; 
    i++;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Assemble code:

```
~$ gcc x.c -S
```

output file name  is `x.s`.

In my case `ebx` register is used, **which may be difference at different compilation time.**

```
~$ cat x.s
    .file   "x.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $28, %esp
    movl    $0, %ebx
    addl    $1, %ebx             // because i++
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    %ebx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    addl    $28, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

You can also **disassemble your executable** using `objdunp`:

```
$ gcc x.c -o x 
$ objdump x -d
```

Partial assembly output using `objdump` command:

```
080483c4 <main>:
 80483c4:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483c5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483c7:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483ca:   53                      push   %ebx
 80483cb:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 80483ce:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 80483d3:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx          //due to i++
 80483d6:   b8 b0 84 04 08          mov    $0x80484b0,%eax
 80483db:   89 5c 24 04             mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
 80483df:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80483e2:   e8 0d ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 80483e7:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 80483ea:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80483eb:   89 ec                   mov    %ebp,%esp
 80483ed:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483ee:   c3                      ret    
 80483ef:   90                      nop
```

`%ebx` register reserved for register variable.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't.

It's decided by the compiler, and might change between compilations if, for instance, the surrounding code changes the [register pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) or if compiler flags are changed.

Comment: Just to be somewhat pedantic the question does say how can he know it, not how can he control it. I agree with Greg Hewgill in his comment that you can determine from the assembler output.

Answer (score 3):

Am too agreeing with UnWind answer, on the other hand disassembling the code in GDB may give the storage of the variables. Disassembling a vague code which I have gives the locals of that frame as below,

```
 (gdb) info locals
 i = 0
 ret = <value optimized out>
 k = 0
 ctx = (BN_CTX *) 0x632e1cc8
 A1 = (BIGNUM *) 0x632e1cd0
 A1_odd = (BIGNUM *) 0x632e1ce8
 check = <value optimized out>
 mont = (BN_MONT_CTX *) 0x632e2108
 A = (const BIGNUM *) 0x632e2028
```

Now if try printing the address of the locals it does tell me the storage location as below,

```
 (gdb) p &i
 $16 = (int *) 0x143fba40
 (gdb) p &k
 $17 = (int *) 0x143fba38
 (gdb) p &mont
 Address requested for identifier "mont" which is in register $s7
 (gdb)
```

Here objects `i` and `k` are on stack and `mont` is in register $s7.

Answer (score 2):

According to the book "The Ansi C Programming Language - Second Edition" of Brian W. Kernighan & Dennis M.Ritchie (The founders of the C languages), ***you can not***.

Chapter 4, Page 84,

> "... And it is not possible to take the address of register variable,
>   regardless whether the variable is actually placed in a `register`."

Hope that helps!
Best of luck in the future,
Ron