# How to store register values using assembly to C++ variables?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

```
int my_var;
void __declspec(naked) stuff()
{
    __asm
    {
        lea edx, [ecx + edi + 0x0000111]
    }
}
```

How to store the value from the address [ecx + edi + 0x0000111] in the c++ variable "my_var" above.

Comment: Answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908835/how-to-store-a-c-variable-in-a-register) might help.

Comment: I'd probably look at the MS docs, like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/accessing-c-or-cpp-data-in-asm-blocks?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @tadman: That's the opposite problem, and not specific to MSVC's flavour of inline asm (which makes it trivial even for local vars that don't have a symbol in the object file or in stand-alone asm).

Comment: @PeterCordes That is handy.

Answer (score 2):

From the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/accessing-c-or-cpp-data-in-asm-blocks?view=msvc-160):

> An __asm block can refer to any symbols, including variable names, that are in scope where the block appears.

Therefore you could do this:

```
int my_var;
void __declspec(naked) stuff()
{
    __asm
    {
        lea edx, [ecx + edi + 0x0000111]
        mov my_var, edx
        ret

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should probably include the missing `ret` instruction this `naked` function needs to be callable without crashing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Did not noticed it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that before and that gave me the address instead of WHAT is in the address, so the actual value.

Comment: @EmreKöycü I assumed you wanted to have the "value" of the register. It might be address of something.  To get the value you want, just define my_var as pointer of a suitable type then dereference it after the _asm block (remember to remove ret instruction) .